# Number of induced paths in an interval graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, discrete-mathematics

Let $G$ be an interval graph. For any two vertices $u,v$ in $G$, how many induced paths are between them in $G$? Is it polynomial in terms of the number of vertices in $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

[image]

Say the total number of intervals is $n$. To get from one red extremity to the other, you can take a path which alternates between green and blue intervals. Each of those paths is induced, and there are $2^\frac{n-2}{2}$ such paths. Thus, the number of induced paths between two vertices in an interval graph is not necessarily polynomial in the number of vertices.